# IOS 7 open modal view not centered

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, modal-dialog

I have a really weird issue after updating my XCode project to Xcode 5 and IOS 7.
My project is a iPad project which open views for editing in modal mode.

After update all my Modal views stop being centered after focus on a textfield (or any input field for that matter)

I open all modal views like this:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"add_log"]) {

    MemberAddLogViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.selfDelegate = self;
    vc.member = self.member;
}
```

And the seque is created with Style = Modal, Presentation = Default, Transation = Default.
If i run it on a IOS6 Simulator the modal view keeps centered, but if a run it on a IOS7 simulator it "snaps" to the left or right after focus is set in a input field with:

```
[self.subject becomeFirstResponder];
```

Anybody else having this issue?

-- UPDATE ---

After hours of this bug annoying me i tried to "redo" the viewcontroller class, and by accident i added the becomeFirstResponder into viewDidLoad and not viewDidAppear and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum and forum conventions do not apply here. Questions are questions, answers are answers, comments are comments. If you have solved your problem, edit your answer (which isn't in fact an answer and therefore risks deletion) to reflect that. Also, one question per question. If you have a new or follow-up question, ask a new queston. In any case read the [faq] and [ask] and [answer].

Comment: Ok, so how do i delete the question?

Comment: You can click on the *close* link below the question, but that is generally inadvisable because if you do too much of that, it will eventually result in an automatic question ban. Another contributing factor to question bans are downvoted questions and questions closed by the community. In your case, I would undelete the answer and just update it with the content of your comment. Maybe somebody else ends up doing the same thing, in which case providing an answer would help that person. Answering your own questions is perfectly fine.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: you can even accept your own answer, that is perfectly sound! You will not get any point, for that, though...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in iOS 7 in landscape mode when I was porting app from iOS6 to iOS7, my UITableViewController was centered but when method becomeFirstResponder was called in viewDidAppear and keyboard showed up the view was moving to the left or right side of the screen depending on rotation direction.
The solution was interesting, I had to run it in main thread:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    });
}
```

and everything is working now. That may help somebody, I was looking for solution in google for few days and did not find any proper solution.